# Reverse Index Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, matrix

- I'm extracting a sub matrix from a quadratic matrix using a list of
  indexes.
- The index list applies to both rows and columns.
- The sub matrix is updated.
- Finally the sub matrix is merged back in the original matrix.
- The extract function is short and fast.
- The merge function is longer and slower, as explicit loops are killing performance
- **Is there a better way of writing merge**?

  ```
  import numpy as np

  def extract(a,indexes): 
      return a[indexes].T[indexes].T

  def merge(a,indexes,b): 
      for i,ix in enumerate(indexes):
          for j,jx in enumerate(indexes):
              a[ix,jx] = b[i,j]
      return a

  N = 10
  a = np.array(np.arange(N*N)).reshape(N,N)

  indexes = [0,2,4,6,8]
  b = extract(a,indexes)

  print(a)
  print(indexes)
  print(b)

  # make some changes in b
  b=-b

  res = merge(a,indexes,b)
  ```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays

```
a:
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49]
 [50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59]
 [60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69]
 [70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79]
 [80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89]
 [90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]]

indexes: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]

b: 
[[ 0  2  4  6  8]
 [20 22 24 26 28]
 [40 42 44 46 48]
 [60 62 64 66 68]
 [80 82 84 86 88]]

res:  [[  0,   1,  -2,   3,  -4,   5,  -6,   7,  -8,   9],
       [ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19],
       [-20,  21, -22,  23, -24,  25, -26,  27, -28,  29],
       [ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39],
       [-40,  41, -42,  43, -44,  45, -46,  47, -48,  49],
       [ 50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59],
       [-60,  61, -62,  63, -64,  65, -66,  67, -68,  69],
       [ 70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79],
       [-80,  81, -82,  83, -84,  85, -86,  87, -88,  89],
       [ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to form such a grid spread across rows and columns. So, simply index into input array with it and assign the negated `b` values, like so -

```
idx_grid = np.ix_(indexes, indexes)
a[idx_grid] = -b
```